# Setting default model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

Considering a `Thing` model and serializer defined like this:

```
# models/thing.rb
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
end

# serializers/thing_serializer.rb
class ThingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

In a controller I'd like to serialize my `@thing`, so

```
render json: @thing
```

returns as expected

```
{"id":3,"name":"rocket"}
```

However, when I try nesting the response deeper like so:

```
render json: { thing: @thing }
```

the `@thing` is serialized, but not using the defined serializer (outputs all fields).

My question is two-fold:

1. Is there a clean dynamic way to make serializing hashes use the "default" serializer for objects nested inside without using `render json: { thing: ThingSerializer.new(@thing) }`?
2. If so, can this be also applied to collection serializers, so objects don't have to be wrapped like

`render json: { my_key: ThingSerializer::CollectionSerializer.new(@things) }`

Comment: Try .as_json method, it should call serializer. render json: { thing: @thing.as_json }

Comment: Unfortunately this works the same way as `{ thing: @thing }`

Comment: Then, you can redefine those methods (as_json / to_json) in your Model class to show only fields you need.